# Were any congressmen or senators concerned that women’s suffrage would result in anti-war votes?

Tags: world-war-one, women, us-constitution

Suffragist organizations at the onset of WWI held varying views on the war. Carrie Chapman Catt of NAWSA felt that women would be viewed as reliable and patriotic if they supported the war effort. But Alice Paul of the NWP picketed outside the White House and publicly criticized Woodrow Wilson. Her actions were seen as unpatriotic and her picketers were often thrown in jail.  The first female member of congress, Jeanette Rankin, [voted against](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeannette_Rankin#First_congressional_term) the declaration of war on Germany in 1917.

Are there instances (such as speeches or letters) where congressmen and senators expressed concern that, if enfranchised, women would vote in accordance with Alice Paul and Jeanette Rankin’s anti-war views?

To find likely answers, I’ve been comparing a list of those members who voted in favor of the war, to those who voted *against* ratifying the 19th amendment in 1918. But it has been very slow going so I’m wondering if anyone happens to know this, or knows a better way to search for it.

There is a [tally sheet](https://www.visitthecapitol.gov/exhibitions/artifact/us-house-representatives-tally-sheet-declaration-war-germany-april-6-1917) for the House of Representatives, showing who voted in favor of the war declaration. But as of yet I have not found a similar list for the Senate, which voted 82-6 on April 4, 1917.

Comment: [Clearly](https://nyheritage.org/exhibits/recognizing-womens-right-vote/great-war-anti-suffragists-patriotism-and-war-preparedness) opponents of suffrage made this argument, but so far I haven't found evidence regarding legislators per se.

Comment: @creative-username  Why would any rational person, such as legislators are hoped to be, be worried about the possibility of it becoming harder to declare war?

Comment: @MAGolding Given the number of women who backed the war effort, I would be surprised if anyone thought it would seriously hinder the chance of declaring war. But even rational legislators are not immune to political posturing. There were all sorts of wacky reasons for denying women the right to vote. I just wondered if this might be among them.